# How can I show "article" with "maxBidPrice"?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Picture: [image: More information about the structure of the tables "offer" and "bid". Also a "Expected result" wich is shown the result. <-- really Important]

"ArticleName" of all offers that have achieved the highest prices. It should also output the "maxBidPrice".

I know the Logic but i have a problem to translate it into code.

I wanna really learn SQL, did u know a Page wich is easy to understand ?

```
Select Artikelbez, count(*) MAXGEBOTSPREIS
from Angebot a inner join Gebot g
on g.aid = a.aid
group by a.ARTIKELBEZ, g.GEBOTSPREIS
having count(*) < max(g.GEBOTSPREIS);
```

the Output of max Bid is 1, 1, 1, 1.
Dont be confused I just try to translate it into English.

I hope you can help me.

Best Regards
GreenTea

Comment: Show us your current query attempt!

Comment: Posting homework on SO for help is fine, but the expectation is that you try on your own first, then you explain what you tried, what worked and what didn't work, where you ran into difficulties... Until you do so I will flag the question for closing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - Requests for homework help must include the OP's attempt at solving it.

Comment: ok i tryed but it dont show me the result

Comment: Show us what you tried. If didn't compile (because of syntax errors) show the error message. If it compiled and ran, but produced the wrong result, show us what it produced. If the output is too long, show a representative (small) part of it and explain that the correct answer shouldn't include it. Or if the query you wrote ran without errors but produced no rows in the output, say so.

Comment: of course wait.

Comment: We don't know how much you know and how much you don't know. Without anything from you, we must guess. We will tell you things you already know, and we will not help you with the things you don't know. Not because we don't want to help; only because we don't have enough information (from you) to be able to help you properly.

Comment: I posted it ^^.